# How to pass in data into the Artisan handle command - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I would I pass data into my handle method I made in my Artisan Command?

This is what I have so far: 
( If I DD something in the handle method, it works, so its linking with the Artisan Command )

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $slug) {

        // Get the user assocated with Listing, and also get the slug of listing.
        $listing = $request->user()->listings()->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        // Flash success message after every update
        Message::set('Alright!', 'Your changes were saved successfully.');



        Artisan::call('emails:sendIfGuideUpdated');

// More code here...
}
```

My Artisan Command that I made to handle sending the emails:

```
class SendEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'emails:sendIfGuideUpdated';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send out an email every minute to users that have favored a guide when that Guide updates their Listing';

    public $listing;


    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Listing $listing)
    {
        $this->listing = $listing;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Get the data from the Guide Listing that was updated

        $name = $this->listing->name;
        dd($name);

        // Send an email to the Admin notifying that a comment was made under a blog post.

    }
}
```

And this is my Kernal file that will handle when the emails get sent out:

```html
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
         Commands\Inspire::class,
         Commands\SendEmails::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('emails:sendIfGuideUpdated')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Im having trouble passing in the Listing information into to handle method. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to update the signature of the command like this : `protected $signature = 'emails:sendIfGuideUpdated {listing}';`

And leave the `__construct` blank.

Then your handel method will looks like this :

```
public function handle()
{
    // Get the data from the Guide Listing that was updated
    $listing = $this->argument('listing')
    $name = $listing->name;
    dd($name);

    // Send an email to the Admin notifying that a comment was made under a blog post.

}
```

Also the call of this command will be :

```
Artisan::call('emails:sendIfGuideUpdated', ['listing' => $listing]);
```